# php myadmin time and date for hestorical records

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm developing an application for managing delivery in a company using netbeans and php myadmin.
I have to save in the database daily hundreds of deliveries with specific data for each but all with the date of that day, for query later like

`select * from table_1 where 'date'='02/10/2016'` for example.
I can create a field in the table with type  "date"  but this date will be  redundancy hundreds of times in the table just to specify one day, and the next day also and so on...
What's the best way to stop the redundancy ??

Answer (score 1):

You could use `datetime` as its `type` which will reduce your redundancy.

And when you wish to retrive all entries of a particular date, you could try using `select * from table_1 where 'date' LIKE '2016-10-02%'` in your query

Comment: do you mean that i can make the property of a table as datetime or just the field ??

Comment: I meant make the type of column `date` as `datetime`